# Can't extract really long file name with 7-zip

Tags: powershell, 7-zip

I have scoured [this page](http://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797/thread/67334954/) which seems to be the only info I can find on extracting really long file names. Although the examples in this page deal with compressing, I would think the same principles apply to extracting.

From what the article says, I would think I would build my command line like this:

```
&7z "x" "\\<ourServer>\glassfish\$Tier\$DeployShare\$FileName" "-o\\?\\\<ourServer>\glassfish\$Tier\$DeployShare\$ApplicationDirectory\"
```

I have tried this and several other derivatives, but have not come close yet to having a command that uses the "support for names longer than 260 characters" that I am seeing all over google. I am running this command inside powershell.

EDIT: I should add that this process is extracting a war file built by Grails. This is not just a compressed file that we manually compressed.

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to ask your question on the 7zip forum that you linked to?

Comment: Good idea, I have done so.